# How to get Permission result callback in DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Here is my Code sample.

```
public class DialogPermission extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getView() {
        View root = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.frg_dialog_permission, null, false);
        Button btnRead = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_read_contact_permission);
        btnRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)){
                    }else{
                      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},101);}
                }
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        Log.e("DialogPermission","Ho! Ho! Ho!");  // Log not printed
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

I don't want callback in Activity.
I hope everything is explained clearly.

Comment: just use        `requestPermissions(new String[{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 101);` not `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions..`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get Request permission result in same dialog use  requestPermissions method of `DialogFragment` class.

```
public class DialogPermission extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View getView() {
        View root = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.frg_dialog_permission, null, false);
        Button btnRead = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btn_read_contact_permission);
        btnRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)){
                    } else{
                      requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},101);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        Log.e("DialogPermission","Ho! Ho! Ho!");  // Log printed
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this in your parent activity and implement listener in your fragment.